# C# Turning Modal form to Modeless

Tags: c#, forms, modal-dialog, modeless

I have a modal form but I need to change it to modeless. The form's purpose is to receive user input, either click OK or Cancel, then continue with further functionality in the same method. I know the sources I've found say just to change form.ShowDialog() to form.Show(), but I'm having trouble with it. When I change it to form.Show(), code continues to be hit and the dialog box doesn't pop up until the entire method has been hit. How do I open the form and handle it within the one method I have?

Sorry if this is poorly worded, still trying to grasp concepts with C#! Thanks!

Comment: If you want the code in your method to wait for user input from the form, then the form must be modal.

Comment: The `ShowDialog` method will block the thread on that statement until the shown form is closed. The `Show` method however, will show the form and continue to run any code after.

Comment: Hook up a closed event in you method and call the continuation

Comment: Change it to Show() and move the remaining code to a new function.  Register with that new forms on_closing or on_closed event to call the new function where it will continue once the form is closed.